# What is the blanket statement for insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

For every input 'n' can we say the upper bound of insertion sort is O(n^2) and lower bound is omega(n)?  Or is it only O(n^2)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every input, time complexity is `O(n^2)+Omega(n)=O(n^2)` because `Omega(n) = O(n^2)`. Notice [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

> Note that "=" is not meant to express "is equal to" in its normal mathematical sense, but rather a more colloquial "is"

For second part of your question, it depends on what type of lower bound you are interested in.

> Omega(n) in the best case so the lower bound is at least Omega(n)

If you want **lower bound for all inputs**, then yes. Considering the best input gives you the lower bound. If you want **lower bound for any algorithms solving the same problem**, you need to consider the algorithm over all possible inputs.